# Issues with Middleware | Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\HasPermission::handle()

Tags: laravel

This is the error I'm receiving when I try to load my index page

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\HasPermission::handle(), 2 passed in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 180 and exactly 3 expected
```

I'm using Spatie's Roles and Permissions Package, and have created a custom middleware HasPermission, to check if the user has the permissions to access and utilise the page they are trying to view.

This is the middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;


class HasPermission
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$permissions)
    {

        $permissions_array = explode('|', $permissions);
        foreach($permissions_array as $permission){
            if (!$request->user()->hasPermission($permission)){
                return redirect()->back();                        
            }
        }    
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use DB;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Http\Middleware\HasPermission;
    
class UserController extends Controller
{
    
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('permission:usermgmt.users|usermgmt.users.create|usermgmt.users.edit|users.delete', ['only' => ['index','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:usermgmt.users.create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:usermgmt.users.edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:users.delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
    }
```

And my routes

```
Route::middleware('HasPermission')->group(function() {
Route::get('/usermgmt/users', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('usermgmt.users');
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
Route::get('add-user', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'create'])->name('usermgmt.users.create');
Route::delete('users/{user}',[App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');
Route::get('users/{user}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'edit'])->name('usermgmt.users.edit');
});
```

I have added the HasPermission middleware class to the Kernel.php, but am struggling to understand why I am receiving that error.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

I tried initially removing the Route Middleware Group and instead trying to do everything in the controller, and tried something like the below

```
$this->middleware(HasPermission::class, ['usermgmt.users','usermgmt.users.create','usermgmt.users.edit','users.delete'], ['only' => ['index','store']]);
```

But this would give me the same error as before.

Comment: `Route::middleware('HasPermission')` this calls the middleware with only the default 2 params, why don't you just check if `auth()->user()->canAny([....]);` in your middleware or use the middlewares that come with spatie? Otherwise you can pass arguments to the middleware with `:arg1|arg2|arg3` notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this way:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$permissions)
    {
        foreach($permissions as $permission){
            if (!$request->user()->hasPermission($permission)){
                return redirect()->back();                        
            }
        }    
        return $next($request);
    }
```

The in your controller, change the syntax:

```
$this->middleware('permission:usermgmt.users,usermgmt.users.create,usermgmt.users.edit,users.delete', ['only' => ['index','store']]);
```